# Connect MySQL workbench to AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need a clear and well explained guide on connecting my free tier RDS to workbench. All the guides I have found are old, the pictures are out of date, and they're not clear where the required pieces are coming from. I am confused because they are talking about EC2 when I am looking for RDS. Please explain this further or include a link to a guide.

Comment: Check the inbound and outbound rules. Maybe the RDS is behind a VPC without internet access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the process is very simple check below screenshot. Add the relevant information your RDS Host String, RDS Username and Add the password by clicking on "Store In Keychain" and make sure your machine IP address is added to the Security Group of the AWS RDS instance.

[image]

Comment: For my ip address that needs to be added to the security group is that the ip address of my house or my ip address given to me by the router?

Comment: When I try and add that to the inbound and outbound for the security group it says invalid.

Comment: Thank you. You did me a big favor. Maybe I am really bad at googling or but searching for this returns really complex not easy to understand guides.

Comment: Well you always have SO :)

Comment: One last thing, I am trying to write a simple query. Use {database name}; show tables; explain {table name}; select * from {table name}; Workbench crashes.

Comment: That I don't know why it is crashing? I will suggest restart the Workbench or the machine and then try? Work bench is not stable many time when we use it on Mac and crashed for me too so I just restart the machine. I don't know if you are using MAC or Windows.

Comment: I will restart, could it be because of my outbound rules for VPC? I left that at default and that is 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: No it has nothing to do with the VPC . If there was issue with VPC connection it will give you connection time out error